# How to solve this error? - 'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for axml file

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

Am new to Xamarin and is currently building a very simple app using the tutorial from Youtube. Am just in a middle of the video when I got this error even tho I carefully followed all instructions. And even the instructor in the video was able to run his app successfully

[image: CLICK THIS FOR IMAGE REFERENCE]

Here's the code where I'm getting the error:

```
var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SignUp, container, false);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Oh okay sorry, thanks for that. I thought it's better for people to see the whole scenario, anyway, here's the code where I'm getting the error:
var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SignUp, container, false);

Comment: If you post 1 line of code, do you think people will be able to help you?  You need to post more details on your problem

Comment: Well, actually that's the only code that I wrote so far, other codes are just the basic auto-generated codes and others are just the normal axml file. Besides, the whole code can be seen in the image, I just highlighted the line where the error exists.

Okay maybe it was my bad to post something with little details, as I was going to edit it but SO won't let me so I just left it as it is. So I'm getting an error whereas the intellisense won't show my newly created axml file (under layout). It only shows the Main.axml

Comment: Also, don't know if this is correct or if it will help with this issue but, I've noticed that in my resource.designer.cs, it doesn't reflect the new layout that I created, it only shows the Main.axml. I am new to programming so please bear with me. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just deleted my newly created axml file, rebuild, add it again, and this time, clean and rebuild.

Everytime I added a new axml file, I clean and rebuild. That's all, thank you :).

Comment: // Command that error code and clean and rebuild, it works for me, no need to remove and add

Answer (score 11):

For me it is caused by namespace changes. After I corrected the namespace in project properties, then I can build again

Comment: Yes, I had to change the default namespace after renaming things.

Comment: I had changed namespace in properties not realizing side-effect would be this. If you had not answered this I would have probably spent few more hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Actually this problem occurs when your ResourceDesigner.cs file has not yet mapped the file that you added to your resource directory.
The easiest way i would suggest to handle this situation is you comment the code you are trying to write and clean build your project and it will work like a charm. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I clean and build my solution many times so I was so desperate and delete all my newly added axml files, added the same things again but this time, clean and rebuild it after adding each axml file. Surprisingly, it worked

Comment: you actually don't need to delete the file just commenting the part where you reference it and building it once will do the trick @Len

Comment: Ahh good thing to know, that will come in handy for future projects. Thank you so much

Comment: Sure man just mark it as the correct ans if you are satisfied so they can close this issue up Thank you. @Len

Comment: Why this possible bug is not yet fixed? Sigh!

Comment: Well this is logically not a bug but yeah you can call it one since it is expected to not happen, the best way to handle this is build your Android project each time you add a resource file

Answer (score 1):

In my `Resource.Layout.toolbar`, Resource was ambiguous between `Android.Resource` and `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource`. Instead the one that works for me is `[Project name].Droid.Resource`. Clean, deleted bin/debug and now it's fine

Answer (score 1):

`Resource.designer.cs` was excluded from project. Solved by including back.

Comment: Oh man, Thank you so was mine!

Answer (score 0):

In `Xamarin.Android` this problem can be resolved by saving other axml/xml file. Many times cleaning solution, deleting bins/obj doesn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my Main file was configured in the Build Action as *AndroidResourceAnalysisConfig* and then change property to *AndroidResource* then Build my project and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of "XXX" does not contain "XXX" errors like this after a git reverse operation. Very annoying.

I tried all the solutions I could find, all without luck. Finally I magically fixed it by going to the Android project properties, Android Options, then unchecked "Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)". I then built the project and it worked. Then I went back and checked that option so it was back to normal, and everything is fine.